# Firebase Database Usage Questions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-nativescript

I'm building out a NativeScript application using nativescript-plugin-firebase.
I'm running into to some issues regarding the consistency of the data in the app each time I close and open the app but before I get to my issues (that I will post later if this post does not help) I have a few fundamental understanding questions regarding the usage of Firebase Database and the benefit of local data storage.

1) This option `persist: true`. Does this do anything by itself, or do I have to use this with conjunction with either `singleEvent: false` in the query OR running `firebase.keepInSync()`?

2) Do I need `persist: true` to be added in order to benefit from `firebase.keepInSync()`?

3) If I have `persist: true` in my init and my query is set to `singleEvent: false`, do I still need to call `firebase.keepInSync()` in order to keep the data in sync?

4) I have about 6 data streams from firebase that I display throughout the app on each "page". Is it better to have `singleEvent: true` on each of these that get fired each time the user views the page. Or is there any benefit to having `singleEvent: false` on all these pages listening continuously.

5) Are there any memory usage warnings I should be aware of when using many `singleEvent: false` throughout the app.

6) I also understand `firebase.keepInSync()` takes up memory. Can this crash my app if I have too many of them active throughout my app?

My bad for the many questions. 
Any enlightenment would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share some insights to this. I am also a bit unclear on the concepts and having trouble with unwanted data caching.